# Android TabLayout can't be instanciated

Tags: android

I added a `TabLayout` to my view in android. In the Layout editor I get following notice:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Motion easing theme attribute must be an @interpolator resource for ?attr/motionEasing*Interpolator attributes or a string for ?attr/motionEasing* attributes.
    at com.google.android.material.motion.MotionUtils.resolveThemeInterpolator(MotionUtils.java:74)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:614)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:509)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:351)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:200)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:161)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:294)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:417)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:428)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:332)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:359)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:436)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:717)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$9(RenderTask.java:873)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:192)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

When I launch the application, it doesn't crash, but the `TabItem`s, which I added with a `TabLayoutMediator`, are not visible.

What is the reason of this error?

My AppTheme inherits from `Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: I think you are using material:1.8.0-alpha01. Downgrading to material:1.7.0-rc01 might help you.

Comment: I know, I created a issue in the git repository

Comment: I added a comment to your issue about TextInputLayot and MaterialCardView  - same error

Answer (score 9):

if you using material:1.8.0-aplpha01, just download material:1.7.0-rc01 to fix this problem

Comment: Yes, it's a known bug in the 1.8.0, but downgrading is not a possible solution for me.